# App for Managing Comments on Blogs

Tags: blogging, comments

I comment on a number of blogs and I'm wondering if there is any utility or software out there that allows you to manage things like this?

For example, many times I will stumble upon a blog and leave a comment on a post.  Ideally I'd like to know if the author responds so I can go in and continue the discussion.

I find that over the course of a day I might do this like 5 times and if I don't regularly follow the sites I'm commenting on that means I'd be bookmarking 5 links a day, and checking them day after day for updates.

Note... this is NOT for spamming so please don't hose me down with blog spamming software.  thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is (or was) an identical question to this here somewhere, but I can’t find it.

In the meantime, many blogs support multiple forms of user-logins for comments including the third-party service [Disqus](http://disqus.com/). You can sign up with them, then sign into a given blog (that includes it as an option), and post your comment, then receive a notification when someone replies. That way you don’t have to sign up specifically for individual blogs.

As a side note, my personal solution is what you mentioned: to simply drag a link to that page to a folder on my system and once in a while when I have nothing to do, go through some and check if I got a response. Granted, it’s not efficient, but it gives me something to kill a few minutes of “useless time” here or there once in a while without resorting to Solitaire. (But then, I don’t usually care about responses, and on the occasion that I do, I put that link in a subfolder.)

Answer (score 1):

- many blogs provide a separate feed for comments of any post
- [coComment](http://www.cocomment.com/) appears to be able to track comments on any blog
- some sites use comment systems [IntenseDebate](http://www.intensedebate.com/) or [Disqus](http://disqus.com/), which can provide notifications